# Xampp (Ver 3.2) Mysql can't start

Tags: xampp, mariadb

Xampp: After deleting some database from MySQL data MySQL can't start, return the following error, Before its working good after delete database only the issue. How to solve the issue. Actually deleting database from mysql->data not from PhpMyadmin.

error :

```
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2020-05-12 18:40:20 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
InnoDB: VirtualAlloc(139984896 bytes) failed; Windows error 8
InnoDB: Error: Block 2609BCB0 incorrect state BUF_BLOCK_POOL_WATCH in buf_LRU_block_free_non_file_page()
200512 18:40:20 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787137 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!VerSetConditionMask()
ntdll.dll!VerSetConditionMask()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: mariaDB not MySQL, its getting more and more relevant to get this right as the 2 diverge

Comment: Do you mean that you deleted files from the `mysql/data/` folder ?

Comment: Yes, not all only database.

Comment: That would explain the mess

Comment: Before everything working, after deleted database from mysql-> data MySQL not start from xampp control panel

Comment: Yes, its a bit cleverer than access. It sees a missing file(s) and that causes it problems

Comment: how to solve this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213700/discussion-between-zus-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: What files did you delete? Do you have a backup?

Comment: I just deleted the database file from mysql->data otherwise nothing.

Comment: You mean you deleted `ibdata1`

Comment: yes, you  are right.

Comment: Anything else i need to do after deleted database file from mysql->data?

Comment: I would uninstll mariaDB the reinstall it. Then start again, and this time the first thing I would do is read up on Backup and Restore

Comment: How to do uninstall and install maria db from xampp?

Comment: BAckup anything/everything you created. Uninstall XAMPP then reinstall XAMPP and then put back what you backed up